# How to get data from GA4 (Google Analytics 4)?

Tags: database, google-analytics-4

I have a Google Analytics (GA4) property setup. I want to extract data from that property on incremental basis. How can I do that ? also I don't want to connect my property to BigQuery or some other 3rd party sites. Is it even possible to get data ?

I have tried using PowerBI's 2.0 connector but it is not working. when I try to load it takes a lot of time and at the end it says timeout error. So, I want to extract the data without using PowerBi, BigQuery and 3rd party sites

Answer (score 0):

No direct connection. PowerBI won't be able to handle it in any capacity unless you use an intermediary. Whether that intermediary is BQ (best practice) or anything else doesn't matter.

GA has seamless export to BQ, but if you want to export the data elsewhere, there's a painful option of using GA's [reporting api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1), which they renamed into Data API recently. But that API is very awkward to use plus it has multiple awkward limitations that force you to implement both horizontal and vertical batching logic in your exports scripts, so vast majority of ETL experts go through the BQ route.

Comment: If I want to go with BQ then are there any limitations? like related to pricing and all..

Comment: BQ is paid, but it's quite cheap in general unless you start writing heavy queries there. Basically, Google realized that GA UA was too good (and expensive to maintain) for a free product, so they pretended to release a new and better shiny version of it while actually cutting its functionality severely and pushing users to use BQ and get paid that way.